# Catch exception in Java parameters

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, annotations, spring-aop

How can I catch in exception in Java *parameters*

Just one example, in code like this

```
MyClass obj = null;
logger.info("the field is " + obj.field);
```

a null pointer exception is thrown.   Is there a way to automatically do this:

```
MyClass obj = null;
try {
  logger.info("the field is " + obj.field);
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Perhaps using Spring AOP, annotations, etc?

Edit:  I want something that will catch any exception,  so that I never have an exception thrown from a line of code that tries to log.

Comment: Is silently consuming the exception what you really want?  Why not something like `logger.info("the field is " + obj == null ? "null" : obj.field);`?

Comment: you can't, and aop won't be of any help here. how about making a toString implementation on your class with every information needed and just appending your reference to the string? this way you don't need to worry about nullity (if null the string "null" will be displayed)

Comment: i want to make the code immune to any exception in the params (so logging isn't able to take us down).   this one is just an example

Comment: I have never heard of any logging framework throwing an exception from a logging method.  Is there a reason you believe this could happen?

Comment: see example in q

Comment: This is bad design. But for what it is worth, you can write an aspect taking care of error handling for log calls. Using a preprocessor like you described is just insane and ugly.

Comment: how do i write an aspect like that?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. And you shouldn't do wrap your code in try catch. This may avoid you some runtime exceptions but also could hide real code issues. You could use the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). You create a marker class with empty fields and if a value in your code should be null you assign it to an instance of this marker class. That should work for code under your control, however it doesn't guarantee third party libraries wouldn't throw NPE.

> Edit: I want something that will catch any exception, so that I never have an exception thrown from a line of code that tries to log.

That can never be achieved. What you are asking for essentially is a try catch block at the start to end of the main method. Even though you still can get exceptions from other threads for example

Comment: Thanks, we want to catch all exceptions, not just NPEs.

Comment: we ended up using a preprocessor